# Why apache2-mpm-prefork should be removed when install apache2-mpm-worker?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04, mpm-prefork, mpm-worker

I have a packageA, which depends on `apache2-mpm-prefork`. packageA was installed. Now I tried to install `apache2-mpm-worker`, but the output is:

```
me@XXX:~$ sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
...
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2-mpm-prefork packageA
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-mpm-worker
```

Why? How to install apache2-mpm-worker without touching packageA?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Debian you can have only one apache instance and it should use one of **mpm**'s. Single apache instance can not use multiple **mpm**'s.

You can compile other versions and run them from /opt, but that is not intended. Debian ideology is that if you need multiple instances of some service, you should use multiple servers.

P.S. It is not same for **every** service, but for most of them.

Comment: you mean I can not install both at the same time?

Comment: Yes, using packets from oficial repo you can not install both mpm's.You still can install multiple mpm's on CentOS (and other rmp-based distro, I think), but you can use only one of them.